# how to use controller scope variable in template view in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have scope variable in angularjs controller, let's say :-

```
$scope.newlangSuffix = 'en';
```

And i am trying to include a php file in template using this scope variable :-

```
<div ng-include="'/catalogfilterhtml_{{newlangSuffix}}.php'"></div>
```

but unable to do that. how can i achieve this thing?

Comment: It seems that you are missing the single inverted comma just after the double inverted comma at the start of ng-include.

Comment: It was my typing mistake. i have corrected that thing in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-include="'/catalogfilterhtml_{{newlangSuffix}}.php'"></div>
```

That's incorrect. `ng-include` expects an angular expression. And `'/catalogfilterhtml_{{newlangSuffix}}.php'` is not a valid one, because angular expressions can't contain double mustaches.

A correct one would be

```
<div ng-include="'/catalogfilterhtml_' + newlangSuffix + '.php'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type it like this:

```
<div ng-include ="'/catalogfilterhtml_'+newlangSuffix+'.php'"></div>
```